# How Can I Animate a Label in Kivy?

Tags: python, animation, kivy, label

Ok, My question goes this way **How Can I Animate a Label in Kivy**, My apologies if this question is annoyingly way too easy :)

Here is the `Label` in which I want animation. Can I have edits of the code in the comments?

Actually, I am obsessed with this script, racking my brains off to know the way to animate this thingy!!   Pls Help!..

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        lu = Label(text = "This is a label! Pls help me with Animation!")
        return lu

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: what animationd to you means? If you want update text every few milliseconds then you could use [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) to execute own function every few milliseconds and this function should update text in label.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update text on `Label` every few seconds then you can use  [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) and `Clock.schedule_interval(function_name, seconds)` to execute `function_name(dt)` every `seconds` and in this function you should change text in `Label`

---

Minimal example which displays current time.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
import datetime

def update_label(dt):
    new_text = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S') 
    label.text = new_text
    #print(new_text)
    
label = None  # create global variable to access the same `label` in two different functions 

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global label  # inform function to assign `Label` to global variable

        label = Label(text="???")
        Clock.schedule_interval(update_label, 1)

        return label

#Clock.schedule_interval(update_label, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another example which scroll text

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
import datetime

label = None

text = 'Hello World of Python!'
text_length = len(text)

index = 0
temp_text = text + ' ' + text

def update_label(dt):
    global index
    
    label.text = temp_text[index:index+15]
    index += 1
    
    if index >= text_length:
        index = 0
    
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global label
        
        label = Label(text="???")
        Clock.schedule_interval(update_label, 0.20)
        
        return label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

---

**EDIT:**

For numerical values you can use [Animation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.animation.html).

Here is blinking text.

It changes color to `black` (in 0.2 second) and next it change back to `white` (in 0.2 second). And it repeats it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
    
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):

        label = Label(text='Hello World of Python!')

        anim = Animation(color=(0, 0, 0, 1), duration=.2) + Animation(color=(1, 1, 1, 1), duration=.2)
        anim.repeat = True
                
        anim.start(label)
            
        return label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```